# Chunks loading and sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, voxel

I working on clone of minecraft and i have 2 problem with chunk loading.

First: Determinate chunks to be loaded.

i found one way it's ugly but works fast for me

1. Define 3d array (array) (size : MAX_CHUNKS_X,MAX_CHUNKS_Y,MAX_CHUNKS_Z)
2. Fill 3d array with FALSE
3. While passing from list of chunks checking if chunk inside a vision range
4. if inside set array[chunk_x][chunk_y][chunk_z] = true;
5. After passing list begin bassing array
6. For all array[chunk_x][chunk_y][chunk_z] == false add to LoadingList chunk at chunk_x chunk_y chunk_z

Another ways to less ugly and still fast ?

Code:

```
     ChunksRenderList.clear();
    CChunk* Chunk = NULL;

    s32 RootChunk_X_Location = (floor(RenderCenter.x) / CHUNK_SIZE);
    s32 RootChunk_Y_Location = (floor(RenderCenter.y) / CHUNK_SIZE);
    s32 RootChunk_Z_Location = (floor(RenderCenter.z) / CHUNK_SIZE);

    if(RenderCenter.x < 0)
        RootChunk_X_Location--;

    if(RenderCenter.y < 0)
        RootChunk_Y_Location--;

    if(RenderCenter.z < 0)
        RootChunk_Z_Location--;

    core::vector3s RootChunkLocation(RootChunk_X_Location,RootChunk_Y_Location,RootChunk_Z_Location);

    u32 XZ_ArraySide = (RenderDistance_XZ*2)+1;
    u32 Y_ArraySide  = (RenderDistance_Y*2)+1;
    char array[XZ_ArraySide][Y_ArraySide][XZ_ArraySide];

    memset(array,0,(XZ_ArraySide*XZ_ArraySide*Y_ArraySide));

    for(auto it = Chunks.begin(); it != Chunks.end(); it++)
    {
        Chunk = (it->second);

        if(Chunk->Locked)
            continue;

        if(Chunk->KeepAliveCounter <= 0)
        {
            ChunksUnloadList.push_back(Chunk);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            Chunk->KeepAliveCounter -= WORLD_UPDATE_PERIOD;
            Chunk->DistanceToCamera = RenderCenter.distance_to(Chunk->ChunkAbsolutePosition);
        }

        if(Chunk->ChunkPosition.x >= (RootChunk_X_Location - (s32)RenderDistance_XZ) && Chunk->ChunkPosition.x <= (RootChunk_X_Location + (s32)RenderDistance_XZ))
            if(Chunk->ChunkPosition.y >= (RootChunk_Y_Location - (s32)RenderDistance_Y) && Chunk->ChunkPosition.y <= (RootChunk_Y_Location + (s32)RenderDistance_Y))
                if(Chunk->ChunkPosition.z >= (RootChunk_Z_Location - (s32)RenderDistance_XZ) && Chunk->ChunkPosition.z <= (RootChunk_Z_Location + (s32)RenderDistance_XZ))
                {
                    s32 PositionInMatrix_X = Chunk->ChunkPosition.x - (RootChunk_X_Location - (s32)RenderDistance_XZ);
                    s32 PositionInMatrix_Y = Chunk->ChunkPosition.y - (RootChunk_Y_Location - (s32)RenderDistance_Y);
                    s32 PositionInMatrix_Z = Chunk->ChunkPosition.z - (RootChunk_Z_Location - (s32)RenderDistance_XZ);

                    array[PositionInMatrix_X][PositionInMatrix_Y][PositionInMatrix_Z] = true;

                    Chunk->KeepAliveCounter = CHUNK_LIVE_TIME;
                }


        if(not Chunk->NeightboarsUpdated)
        {
            ChunksNeightboarUpdateList.push_back(Chunk);
        }

        if(not Chunk->ChunkUpdated)
        {
            ChunksRebuildList.push_back(Chunk);
        }
        if(not Chunk->Locked and Chunk->VisibleBlocks > 0)
        {
            ChunksRenderList.push_back(Chunk);
        }

    }

    for(u32 y = 0; y < Y_ArraySide; y++)
        for(u32 x = 0; x < XZ_ArraySide; x++)
            for(u32 z = 0; z < XZ_ArraySide; z++)
            {
                s32 ChunkPosition_X = (s32)x + (RootChunk_X_Location - (s32)RenderDistance_XZ);
                s32 ChunkPosition_Y = (s32)y + (RootChunk_Y_Location - (s32)RenderDistance_Y);
                s32 ChunkPosition_Z = (s32)z + (RootChunk_Z_Location - (s32)RenderDistance_XZ);

                if(array[x][y][z] == 0)
                {

   SPendingToLoad ToLoad;
                    ToLoad.Position.set(ChunkPosition_X,ChunkPosition_Y,ChunkPosition_Z);
                    ToLoad.DistanceToCamera = ToLoad.Position.distance_to_sqr(RootChunkLocation);
                    ChunksLoadList.push_back(ToLoad);
                }
            }
```

Second:
how to sort ChunksLoadList to take effect like left on this pic
https://www.dropbox.com/s/owjfaaekcj2m23w/58f2e4c8.png?dl=0
Red  = nearest to ChunksLoadList.begin()
Blue = farest  to ChunksLoadList.begin()

im try to use

```
    ChunksLoadList.sort([&RootChunkLocation](SPendingToLoad& i,SPendingToLoad& j)
    {

        return i.DistanceToCamera < j.DistanceToCamera;
    }
    );
```

But it method to slow for big vision ranges...
How i must rewrite code to take fast wave-loading effect ?

Sorry me horrible english, i hope you understand me...

Comment: How important is the exact distance to the camera? and the exact order? and are all the values floats?

Comment: Surt, distance to camera need only for sort chunks from nearest to far. Function that calc distance not uses sqrt() only (x^2+y^2+z^2)

Comment: The S32 is int32_t and the variable that are typecast to S32 are float?

Answer (score 0):

Lets first look at the distance sorting problem, if your `ChunksLoadList` is a std::list and not a std::vector or std::array(C++11) you have lost the performance race already! [Bjarne Stroustrup: Why you should avoid Linked Lists](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo) Pay close attention to the graph!!!

If its still too slow after you've changed it into a std::vector you can try "this method I just invented(TM)"!

The best sorting algorithms are something like

> O(C+K*N log log N) [fastest?](http://www.nada.kth.se/~snilsson/fast-sorting/)

With a horrible C constant prep time, horrible K per element and a very nice N log log N

For N -> infinity this gets to be O(N log log N)

**BUT** for this problem there is an even better algorithm!
Flood fill followed by an insertion sort, the flood fill produces a nearly sorted list in O(N) and the insertion sort secures the totally ordered list from the partially ordered in O(N) for a total of O(N) ...

> O(C+K*N)

with a horrible constant prep time, and an awful per element but only N times

[variant of wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)

```
 Flood-fill (node, target-color, replacement-color): 

 If target-color is equal to replacement-color, return.
 Set Q to the empty queue. [must be std::vector or std::array or this will fail]
 Add camera node to the end of Q.
 While Q is not empty: 
     Set n equal to the *first* element of Q.
     Remove *first* element from Q.
     If the color of n is equal to target-color:
         Add n to the distance list as the next closed (this will be nearly correct)
         Set the color of n to replacement-color and mark "n" as processed.
         Add adjacent nodes to end of Q if they has not been processed yet. (x/y/z +1/-1)
 Return.
```

Queue elements are x,y,z
use std::dequeue

The distance list must also be a random access contain, that is fully allocated from start of size (viewdistance*2+1)^3, that is potentially big.
If view distance 100 is 201^3 = ~80000000 voxels, did you really want this? if you need some info from it you must have some pointer or index, at least 4 bytes, this blows the cache away on most systems.

As a flood fill its not effective but as a approximation to distance it is.
You could stop here if your requirements are fulfilled.
*IF* you need total ordered then run an insertion-sort on the [nearly sorted list](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/nearly-sorted-initial-order) O(N), but then you need to calculate the camera distance also.

Potential further optimization:

- opaque voxels doesn't add neighbours that also are opaque.
- air(totally transparent) doesn't add to the camera list but need to be there for the fill, in case a flying island is present.

Comment: Well... 
Estimated view distance 528(16) or 1040(32)
Main problem is - how determine next chunks(or single chunk but nearest to camera) that must to be loaded.
And this "next chunks" need to sort from camera to far
test results for world 9x9x9 view:4
Insertation sort - 19ms
Flood fill alghoritm that you show - 118ms
std::sort(vector) - 0.7ms
for world 33x33x33 view:16
Insertation sort - > 51771ms (dont know why)
Flood fill alghoritm that you show: i make somth wrong and... bad_alloc =) but after test on (9x9x9)... i think need even more than 51771ms..
std::sort(vector) - 51ms

Comment: Insertion sort is only good if the data is nearly sorted and the insertion sort shown in one of the links is also not easily understood, ie. if you implemented it from there you better find another implementation :(

Comment: Changing the queue to a std::dequeue does that help in either case?

Comment: Data in loading list can reversed or nearly sorted

Comment: I would be very interested in how the flood fill code looks like as I wonder if I have not been precise somewhere or it was just a bad idea :)

Comment: Sure - http://pastebin.com/r6ZKceZh .
Or this method very slow for me or i just do it wrong...
In code - ChunkState = 1 - chunk already loaded
ChunkState = 2 - chunk already passed by alghoritm
ChunkState = 0 - still not passed and not loaded...

Comment: I've tried to optimize it (http://pastebin.com/P0y3tQY8) but I'm pretty sure it can't beat a sort on a vector due to locality problems.

Comment: After optimization reult 152ms. (9x9x9) 
Without opt. 160ms.
Still bad... maby find another way to check that chunk must loaded next ?

P.S.
WithAdditional my own opt. 370ms. (i dont realy know why =D) 
(Forgot to say s32 - int and RenderDistance - unsigned int)